# Eclipse plugin: react on closure of view?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse pluging view that extends ViewPart (if that means something). I want to be notified when my view is closed or eclipse is closed entirely to perform some final operations.

How can I get a notification of my view being closed?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IPartService.addPartListener(IPartListener)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener.html).

EDIT: Also, for session close (when Eclipse is shut down) `org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart.saveState(IMemento)` will be called to allow you to save state that can be restored on your next activation.  But it will not be called if the user closes the part.