# how to ask user if he wants to always show welcome page?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application, I have a intro page, which has a few explanations about the product itself.
But the intro only shows up on the first time that the application is opened.
Is there a way to ask user if he wants to 'never show this again on startup'?
my introContent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<introContent>
    <page id="root" content="content/root.xhtml" />
    <page id="concept1" content="content/concept1.xhtml" />
    <page id="concept2" content="content/concept2.xhtml" />

    <contentProvider id="awc"
        class="org.eclipse.ui.intro.contentproviders.AlwaysWelcomeCheckbox"
        pluginId="org.eclipse.ui.intro">
    </contentProvider>
</introContent>
```

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you want ideas of desgn, you should ask on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ If you want implementation help, you'll need to explain what design you want and what is your problem implementing it.

Comment: i don't think you undestood my problem. my welcome page appears only when the application is running for the first time. i want to show it always, and let the user choose if he doesn't want to see the page everytime he opens the application. sorry if i hadn't made my point and sorry about my english

Comment: If nothing else you can probably add a preference page option for this and open it programmatically when your plugin loads.

Comment: +1 for @chris's idea, I think this is the only way you can do it.

Comment: that sounds cool to me. i already have a preference page, which make this easier to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a workbench preference `SHOW_INTRO` defined in [`IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.html). If this is *true* then intro page is opened during startup.

You would have to implement the asking the user part yourself (e.g. by showing a [`MessageDialogWithToggle`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/MessageDialogWithToggle.html) when the Intro view is closed).

Comment: that was my first idea, but i can't (or don't know how) control when the user is closing the welcome page to show my MessageDialogWithToggle, as far as I know.

Comment: @LuizK. [Eclipse plugin: react on closure of view?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8275201/150166). Your real problem (with any solution) is that if your plugin doesn't get activated then your code never executes and you can't control the Welcome page at startup anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

i've done the following:

```
public void postWindowOpen(){
     addPartListener();
}

    private void addPartListener() {
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(new PartListenerAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                    if(part.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewIntroAdapterPart")){
                        //fechou a intro
                        System.out.println(part.getTitle());
                        MessageDialogWithToggle openToggle = MessageHelper.openToggle("Deseja mostrar a ajuda sempre?");
                        if(openToggle.open() == IDialogConstants.OK_ID){
                            if(openToggle.getToggleState()){
                                PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_INTRO, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

it's just an 'alpha' version, but it's working! thank you guys

Comment: i tried, but stackoverflow says i exceeded the maximum characters. weird

Comment: Weird indeed. Instead of checking the class name I would recommend using view ID: `part.getSite().getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview")`.